# Codeigniter: Trying to get property of non object

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I have a condition in javascript that says if the text box is blank it would alert and return false, but it doesn't work instead it submits here is my view

```
frm_otherequips2.php

<form action="edit_delete_others2" method="POST" id='frm_otherequips2' name="frm_otherequips2">
    <fieldset id="edit_other">
        <legend>Inventory Details</legend>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <?php $otherequips = $other->Equipment;
                      $otherdesc = $other->ItemDescription;
                      $otherID = $other->ID;
                      $otherserialnum = $other->SerialNumber;
                ?>
                <td>Equipment</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="txt_editotherequip" name="txt_editotherequip" value="<?php echo $otherequips ?>"/></td>
                <td>Item Description</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="txt_editotherdesc" name="txt_editotherdesc" value="<?php echo $otherdesc ?>"/></td>
                <td style="visibility: hidden;"><input type="text" id="txt_editotherID" name="txt_editotherID" value="<?php echo $otherID ?>"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Serial Number</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="txt_editotherserialnum" name="txt_editotherserialnum" value="<?php echo $otherserialnum ?>"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><button class="btn_editother" id="btn_editother" name="btn_editother" type="submit" value="Edit" onclick="validate_edit_otherequip();">Edit</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

and here is my javascript:

```
    <script>

    function validate_edit_otherequip(){
        if(document.getElementById('txt_editotherequip').value === ""){
            alert('Please Input Equipment!');
            return false;
        }
        else if(document.getElementById('txt_editotherdesc').value === ""){
            alert('Please Input Item Description');
            return false;
        }
        else if(document.getElementById('txt_editotherserialnum').value === ""){
            alert('Please Input Serial Number');
            return false;
        }
        else{
            var y;
            if(confirm("Are you sure you want to save updated data?") === true){
                var y = document.forms['frm_otherequips2'].submit();
            }
            else if(confirm("Are you sure you want to save updated data?") === false){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

What I did is i put return false in controller, here is my controller:

```
public function edit_delete_others2($id){
        $data_other['other'] = $this->inventory_model->other_search($id);
        $this->load->view('homeview');
        $this->load->view('frm_otherequips2', $data_other);
        $this->load->view('footer_view');


        if(!empty($_POST['btn_editother'])){
            if($_POST['txt_editotherequip'] == "") {
                return false;
            }
            else if($_POST['txt_editotherdesc'] == "") {
                return false;
            }
            else if($_POST['txt_editotherserialnum'] == ""){
                return false;
            }
            else{
                 $this->inventory_model->update_others($this->input->post());
                 redirect('inventorysys_controller/view_others', 'refresh');
            }

    }
}
```

But everytime i run it and I leave a blank textbox for example 'txt_editotherequip' is blank it posts the alert and then this error occur:

> **A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>
> Filename: views/frm_otherequips2.php
>
> Line Number: 10
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>
> Filename: views/frm_otherequips2.php
>
> Line Number: 11
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>
> Filename: views/frm_otherequips2.php
>
> Line Number: 12
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>
> Filename: views/frm_otherequips2.php
>
> Line Number: 13**

Please do help me on this one, I've been stuck with this for days. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the onclick event occurs, since you said that the form submits whereas in your code it should have popped up a confirm box or an alert on any case.

```
function validate_edit_otherequip(){
    alert('works!');
    ....
}
```

Check for javascript errors.

Comment: I've replaced "$otherequips = $other->Equipment" in my view with this "echo (isset($other->Equipment) AND $other->Equipment) ? $other->Equipment:'';" with an if condition in my view it worked when I press the edit button and one text box is blank, but when I click OK on the alert the other textboxes becomes blank too.. though  it didn't submit.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `flag variable` and `trim function` in the controller.

```
$flag=1;
if(!empty($_POST['btn_editother'])){
        if(trim($_POST['txt_editotherequip']) == "") {
           $flag=0;
        }
        if(trim($_POST['txt_editotherdesc']) == "") {
            $flag=0;
        }
        if(trim($_POST['txt_editotherserialnum']) == ""){
            $flag=0;
        }
        if($flag == 0) return false;
        else{
             $this->inventory_model->update_others($this->input->post());
             redirect('inventorysys_controller/view_others', 'refresh');
        }

}
```

The error `Trying to get property of non-object` occurs when the model is either unable to fetch data or the data fetched is not an object at all.

Comment: I've tried your code but it still has the error, there is no change.